# Confluence: Variable in Included Template Page

Tags: variables, confluence

Working on some documentation and I'd like to basically be able to do the following

Parent Page:

```
VAR="Content"
{include:Template Page}
```

Template Page:

```
some text using {VAR}
```

Result:

```
some text using Content
```

I tried using the run/run-now macros with variables, but when nested with the {include} the substitution happens before the {include} macro is parsed

Comment: Sorry for commenting on such an old thread, but did you ever get this to work?

Comment: Never did and I gave up unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the easiest way around this would be to add some inline JavaScript in the "template page" which looks for the `VAR="Content"` in the page and rewrites the content from the parent page into the variable on include.

Should be fairly trivial to implement provided the meaning of your `VAR="Content"` an be expanded upon.